# Firebase Hosting web frameworks w/ Angular, selecting environments

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am using the firebase hosting web frameworks experimental feature with an Angular ssr project. I've got everything set up correctly and everything seems to deploy fine, *except* I started getting a bunch of CORs errors because my staging url was not whitelisted. Then I realized that it builds and deploys using the production build pipeline by default. I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that allows you to select an environment configuration. When normally doing a build, you can usually do something like `ng build --configuration staging`. However, the `firebase deploy` command will automatically build your project for you when you're using the web frameworks feature, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify any parameters for your build.

TLDR running `firebase deploy` will build my Angular's project w/ the production configuration only with seemingly no way to change it. Is there a way to specify a configuration to use?

Comment: If there is not actually a way to do what you want (use the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) and `--help` on the command line to discover everything), then what you have is a feature request to file in the [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) repo.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be to use the `FIREBASE_FRAMEWORKS_BUILD_TARGET` variable.

On MacOS: `FIREBASE_FRAMEWORKS_BUILD_TARGET='staging' firebase deploy --only hosting`
On Windows: `set FIREBASE_FRAMEWORKS_BUILD_TARGET='staging' firebase deploy --only hosting`

Support for FIREBASE_FRAMEWORKS_BUILD_TARGET variable is already implemented in recent versions of the firebase-tools.